# Select price depended on other table

Tags: sql

I have two tables 1 is like;

**Cost**

id         taxwork   taxworkbuissnes  taxmaterials   hourrate    extrahourrate drivingcost

**Billing**

id         hours     materials        extrahours     buissnes

What i want to do is call the total cost of the bill

If buissnes = 1 it means it is a buissnes billing and it gets discount on tax for hourrate.

If extrahours = 0 it means i need to use hourrate if it is 1 i need to use extrahourrate

Is it possible to do some kind of if statement so i can get the right totalhourcost, and the right tax.

**edit : added fiddle**

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd8d9/1

Comment: Yeah it is possible. Do you have a query in mind? Also could you give us example data?

Comment: Nope i dont know how to do an if i tryd if and case but cant get it working

Comment: Try setting up your tables and sample data in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/, and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: added fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b60a9/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this to calculate the total hour cost:

```
SELECT B.id,
 Hours
* (CASE WHEN B.extrahours= 1 then C.extrahourrate else C.hourrate END) 
* (1 + CASE WHEN  buissnes=1 then C.taxworkbuissnes/100 else C.taxwork/100 END)
AS TotalHourCost
FROM bill B JOIN cost C ON B.costid = C.id
```

Comment: "*" is just the multiplication operator (to multiply Hours * HourCost). The parenthesis are just to isolate the calculation of hourly rate into a single value, and then to calculate the applicable tax rate as a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on what you are asking, but hope this gets you started

```
SELECT LaborCost,drivingCost,materials,
       Taxes,TaxMaterials,taxes+taxMaterials as TotalTaxes,
       laborCost+drivingCost+materials+Taxes+TaxMaterials as TotalCost
FROM
(
SELECT 
    CASE extraHours
        WHEN 1 THEN (hours*extrahourRate) 
        ELSE (hours*hourRate) END as LaborCost,
        drivingCost,
        materials,
        CASE Buissnes
        WHEN 1 THEN TaxWorkBuissnes ELSE Taxwork END as Taxes,
        TaxMaterials        

FROM bill 
JOIN cost ON bill.costid = cost.id
) xx
```

Comment: Ok what isn't clear i will edit it so its more understandable. The tax is diffrent int your answer tax total = 34 wich can be left because the total would be 14 % of laborcost and 20 % of materials so not 34 in total can do alot with the answer though